# Что означают параметры у массива во вкладке "Console" в инструментах разработчика?

Tags: javascript

Что это означает в консоли?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Немного я знаю, например (сверху-вниз):

1. Массив.
2. Индекс первого элемента, равный 0.
3. Кол-во элементов.
4. ...

Правильно я понимаю что консоль вывела методы, которые допустимо применять к данному массиву? Вот только не пойму, если массивы это в принципе объекты(объекты как ассоциативные массивы, то есть массивы это те же объекты для более удобного хранения данных), то почему здесь нет методов replace, split..? И почему почти везде стоит " *f* " ?

Comment: а почему у _массивов_ должны быть _replace, split_?

Comment: не обязательно, может быть и другие методы. Я так предположил, для примера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы понять, что это заметоды, нужно разработься с таким понятием как `prototype` ([Прототип](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype)). В javascript практически всё, кроме примитивных типов (`number`, `string`, `boolean`, ...), явяляется объектом и, для того, что бы в этом убедиться, выполните в консоли следущий код:

```js
console.log([] instanceof Object); // Массив
console.log({} instanceof Object); // Объект
console.log((function(){}) instanceof Object); // Функция
console.log(new Date() instanceof Object); // Объект даты
```

Говоря является объектом, имеется в виду то, что тот или иной "класс" "наследуется" от "класса" `Object` (если выражаться в терминах ООП). Но в прототипных языках наследование рееализуется через прототипирование. Другими словами, в основе объекта `Array` лежит объект `Object` и связь между ними, в javascript, реализуется посредством свойства `__proto__`.

```js
const list = new Array();

// здесь Array - это "класс", а list - это объект "класса"

// Array базируется на "классе" Object и в этом можно убедиться, если вылнить такую команду

console.log(Array.prototype.__proto__.constructor.name); // Object

// здесь:
// Array - это сам "класс"
// Array.prototype - это прототип "класса" Array
// Array.prototype.__proto__ - это уже Object, который лежит в основе прототипа объекта. Т.к. для того что бы реализовать прототип, в любом случае потребуется воспользоваться объектом.
// Array.prototype.__proto__.constructor.name - это способ вывесит имя  данного объекта
```

Что косается `f`, то это просто способ отображения функции в консоли браузеров `Chromium`. Если вы выполните этот же код в браузере Firefox, то в его консоли вывод будет примерно таким `function toString()`

Answer (score 3):

Консоль хрома пытается выводить в читаемом виде реальные свойства объекта. Для стандартных типов вроде Array, String и т.д. выводимые свойства в основном соответствуют спецификации.

Например для [`Array`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-array-objects) выводятся непосредственно элементы массива, в данном случае один элемент с индексом 0 и значением - строка.

После свойств непосредственного объекта, указывается его прототип, в консоли хрома он, пока, отображается как `__proto__`.

При раскрытии его указываются свойства описанные в разделе спецификации [Properties of the Array Prototype Object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object)

И так далее, можно раскрывать `__proto__` пока само свойство не будет `null`.

---

В случае с функциями, кроме свойств описанных в спецификации, в разделе [Function Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-function-objects) также указываются служебные свойства

1. `[[FunctionLocation]]` - в значении которой указывается ссылка на отладчик с исходником этой функции
2. `[[Scopes]]` - непосредственно используемые замыкания.

Comment: "в консоли хрома он, пока, отображается как __proto__"  - но может и по другому?

Comment: @ikar, вполне. По желанию левой пятки разработчиков хрома. Так как отображение в консоли нигде не регламентировано.

Answer (score 1):

1. Метод `replace` и `split` - это методы строки. У массива есть свои методы, у строки свои, у обьекта - свои. По своей сути, всё что есть в `javascript`(типы данных) - наследуется от Обьекта(через `__proto__`).
2. Буква `f` означает что это - функция, рядом с этой буквой стоит имя функции.

Comment: 1) Получается каждый раз(если не знаешь или не помнишь) что возвращает та или иная переменная необходимо проверять через typeof, затем применять соотвествующие свойства и методы. 2) букву "f" Chrome подсказал что это, меня больше интересовало почему там такие строчки. Или просто консоль как-бы показывает что функцию можно обозвать названием метода и в теле функции применить уже сам этот метод?